# (Ruby) How to dump a database?

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, postgresql, dump

I want to do a database dump through Ruby scripting, but I didn't find any class or script for do that.

Ideally the dump should work for MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, etc. (at least MySql and Pg). I tried with DBI but I can't.

Other way is doing table for table ... D:

**Edit 1:**
It's only for backup, no restore.
For now I have troubles with hostings, because I need to ask for permits to my IP, so I will try with SSH.

Comment: "trying with DBI but I can't." -- What problems are you running into?

Comment: because with DBI I can't do a dump, but I can get the info table per table, but this is to slow to do.

Comment: @Joseph What should the dump look like? Do you need to be able to restore just the data to memory it in another Ruby session (e.g. using Marshal)? Do you need to be able to load it back into another database? Do you need raw SQL code? You must supply more details about what you are trying to accomplish (your end goals) if you want better help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using exec in your script to run the mysqldump app?

```
exec 'mysqlinstalldir/bin/mysqldump -u username -ppassword --databases databasename'
```

You should be able to do the same with Postgresql and pg_dump

Answer (score 5):

you can use your system tools for taking dump of database,run this script in your code may be a rake task

```
system "mysqldump database_name table1 table2 -u root -p password > path/to/dump/file "
```